# Explain why does Tensorflow throw "Attempting to use uninitialized value" during linear transform

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to apply `tf.layers.dense` on a tensor while running jupyter notebook. The code I am using raises `FailedPreconditionError`:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_9/bias
     [[Node: dense_9/bias/read = Identity[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@dense_9/bias"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dense_9/bias)]]
```

Jupyter notebook code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.InteractiveSession()
batch_size = 3
seqlen = 5
nfeats = 3
mini_batch = np.random.randint(1,10, (batch_size, seqlen, nfeats))
d = dict((n, t.eval()) for n,t in enumerate(tf.unstack(mini_batch, 3)))
d0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(d[0],dtype=tf.int32)
d0 = tf.reshape(d0, [seqlen, batch_size])
d0_lin = tf.layers.dense(inputs=d0, units=100)
d0_lin.eval()
```

I am new to Tensorflow and the idea I am playing with is how to apply linear transformation on a `5x3` tensor and transform it into `5x100` tensor when you have a `3x5x3` input tensor. So that we could convert `3x5x3` tensor to `3x5x100` tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you were getting a `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value`, I Initialising the global variables and that made it work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.InteractiveSession()
batch_size = 3
seqlen = 5
nfeats = 3
mini_batch = np.random.randint(1,10, (batch_size, seqlen, nfeats))
d = dict((n, t.eval()) for n,t in enumerate(tf.unstack(mini_batch, 3)))
d0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(d[0],dtype=tf.int32)
d0 = tf.reshape(d0, [seqlen, batch_size])
d0_lin = tf.layers.dense(inputs=d0, units=100)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(d0_lin.eval())
```

output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```